# OnLongClickListener not working with onTouchListener

Tags: java, android

I am making a scoreboard class that is being used to control a layout that has the user swipe up and down to increase and decrease the score; then long click the screen to reset the score. I have the OnTouchListener working properly at this point by creating a separate OnSwipeTouchListener class and then calling the methods inside it on the element that is being touched. But after running the program again, my LongClickListener has stopped responding. My best guess is that the TouchListener just overrides everything else automatically, but I'm not certain. I will link related classes below so anyone can see my implementation exactly. Would anyone be able to assist with this or recommend an alternative?

Scoreboard.java

```
package com.example.seth.sidespin;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;

public class Scoreboard extends Fragment{

    private int counter_left = 0;
    private int counter_right = 0;


    private RelativeLayout rl_left, rl_right;
    private TextView tv_left, tv_right;




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scoreboard,null);


        rl_left = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_left_score);
        rl_right = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_right_score);
        tv_left =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_left_score);
        tv_right = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_right_score);




        rl_left.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getContext()) {

            public void onSwipeUp() {

                counter_left++;
                tv_left.setText(Integer.toString(counter_left));

            }
            public void onSwipeDown() {
                if (counter_left > 0) {
                    counter_left--;
                }
                tv_left.setText(Integer.toString(counter_left));

            }
        });

        rl_right.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getContext()) {

            public void onSwipeUp() {

                counter_right++;
                tv_right.setText(Integer.toString(counter_right));

            }
            public void onSwipeDown() {
                if (counter_right > 0) {
                    counter_right--;
                }
                tv_right.setText(Integer.toString(counter_right));

            }
        });


        rl_left.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                counter_left = 0;
                tv_left.setText(String.valueOf(counter_left));
                counter_right = 0;
                tv_right.setText(String.valueOf(counter_right));
                return true;
            }

        });

        rl_right.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                counter_right = 0;
                tv_right.setText(String.valueOf(counter_right));
                counter_left = 0;
                tv_left.setText(String.valueOf(counter_left));
                return true;
            }

        });




        return view;
    }




@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
        getActivity().setTitle("Scoreboard");
    }

}
```

OnSwipeTouchListener.java

```
package com.example.seth.sidespin;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by stins on 4/29/2017.
 */

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
    }

    public void onSwipeUp() {
    }

    public void onSwipeDown() {
    }


    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            if (Math.abs(distanceY) > Math.abs(distanceX) && Math.abs(distanceY) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (distanceY > 0)
                    onSwipeDown();
                else
                    onSwipeUp();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: [quick googling](http://google.com/?q=android+gestures) gives [full instruction](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My best guess is that the TouchListener just overrides everything else automatically, but I'm not certain.

Yes, it does.

Try overriding `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.onLongPress(MotionEvent)` for your long press event.

Comment: Gotcha!! Do I actually override it in that onTouchSwipeListener.java class?

Comment: @KortneyStinson yes, more precisely the `GestureListener` inner class